# Prove-If n is prime $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field.

Tags: ring-theory

I need to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field if and only if $n$ is prime. And I proved the forward. 
But I am not sure how to prove the backward, 'if n is prime $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field.
'

What can I assume from the assumption $n$ is prime?

and What do I need to show?

Comment: You need to show that there are no zero divisors and that every element have an inverse.

Comment: Doesn't the latter imply the former? Say $a$ has an inverse $b$, and it's a zero divisor (with $c$). $ab = 1$, $cab = c$, $0b = c = 0$.

Comment: @IgorRivin But isn't for integral domain?

Comment: @HenrySwanson absolutely, but the OP does not (or did not) know that.

Comment: @HenrySwanson not only that, but every finite division ring is a field, so the former implies the latter!

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that $\Bbb Z_n$ is an integral domain, because every finite integral domain is a field. Suppose we have $ab = 0 \pmod n$, then $n \mid ab$, so $n\mid a$ or $n \mid b$ since $n$ is prime (Euclid's lemma), so $a$ or $b$ is zero in $\Bbb Z_n$. So $\Bbb Z_n$ is an integral domain.

To see that every finite integral domain is a field, take powers of a nonzero element $a$. Since there are finitely many elements, we must have repeats, say $a^n= a^m$ for $n > m$. So $a^n-a^m=0$, so $a^{m}(a^{n-m} - 1) = 0$. If $a^m=0$, then $a=0$ by repeatedly applying the integral domain property, so $a^m \neq 0$, since $a$ is nonzero. Thus $a^{n-m}=1$, and $a \cdot a^{n-m-1} = 1$, so $a$ is invertible. Thus, every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse and every finite integral domain is a field.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this is an 'if and only if' statement. So we will show that.

First, assume that $n$ is prime. We show that it is a field (by showing multiplicative inverses for nonzero elements):

If $n$ is prime and $\overline a\ne0$ (that is, $a$ isn't a multiple of $n$) then $a$ and $n$ are coprime. Then by Bezout's theorem there exist $b,c\in\mathbb Z$ such that
$$
ba+cn=1
$$
but that means that $\overline a\;\cdot\overline b=\overline1$.

Now we show that if $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, then $n$ is prime:

Suppose that this isn't so. So $n$ isn't prime. Then $n=ab$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $\overline0=\overline a\;\overline b$, where $\overline a\neq \overline0 $ and $\overline b\neq 0$. But then $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ isn't an integral domain, so it can't be a field!

Comment: What do you mean by a bar on $a$, $b$, $1$?

Comment: @Wes It's standard notation. It is representative of the residue class. For example, suppose we take any integer and divide by $4$. The only remainders we can get are $0$, $1$, $2$, $4$. So suppose we look at all the integers that have remainder $1$ when we divide by $4$, we call those numbers $\overline{1}$, et cetera. We could have even picked $13$, which has remainder $1$ when divided by $4$, but we choose the smallest ones for simplicity. So given $n$, the remainder classes are $\overline{0}, \overline{1},\cdots,\overline{n-1}$.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life Why is it the case that $\bar{a}.\bar{b}=\bar{1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Other than showing trivial axioms, you need to show that every element in $Z/pZ$ has a multiplicative inverse. In other words, given $k$, you need to find $m$ such that $k \cdot m \equiv 1 \pmod p$

This, though, is equivalent to showing that there exists $n$ such that $km = pn + 1$. Because $p$ is a prime, we know that $\gcd(k, p) = 1$. By Euclid's Algorithm/Linear Diophantine Equations, there must exist $(m_0 , n_0)$ such that $km_0 +pn_0 = 1$. The result follows.

I can clarify any of this if you'd like - feel free to comment.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but your notation is little confusing to me. what is Z/pZ?

Comment: @Wes This means the remainders when we divide any integer by the prime $p$. So again as in my comment, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is the set $\{\overline{0}, \overline{1},\cdots,\overline{p-1}\}$.